# Text Qualifier in Format File Causing Data Loss

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm experiencing a rather weird issue with a format file I'm using for SQL Server bulk import. I have a csv file that has 1.4 million rows, and in this file there is a column where all the records are formatted like `New York, NY` which obviously causes issue because of the comma. so in an attempt to rectify this issue, I created a format file and set that particular column as so:

```
11 SQLCHAR 0 50 "\"," 11 "Called To" SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Initially, I thought this worked, as everything seemed to have imported in just fine (With the exception of each of the records in this column having a leading quotation mark, but I cleaned this up with a query). It wasn't until later that I realize that when setting this column to the format that I have, I manage to import all but ONE row of records.

I was able to track down the one record, and there is nothing special or unique about it, at least not on the service, but for some reason it gets left out when importing with this format file. I tried a few different ways of formatting this column in the format file, such as:

```
11 SQLCHAR 0 50 "\",\"" 11 "Called To" SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

And

```
10 SQLCHAR 0 50 ",\"" 10 "Number Called" SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11 SQLCHAR 0 50 ",\"" 11 "Called To" SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

All any of these other solutions do is produce an error of:
`The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 11. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.`

When I take out the text qualifier all together, it imports all the data including that one record that was missing from before. Of course by doing this, it brings me back to the original issue of `New York, NY` having an additional comma that throws the rest of the data off. Is there another way to do a text qualifier in this situation that wont cause data loss? Better yet, does anyone have an idea why it would import all by 1 record? Here is snippit of the record that has gone missing on import, `Call To` would be column 11 in the format file.

```
Time    Number Called      Call To     Minutes used
3:03  (xxx) xxx-xxxx      VMAIL, CL      1
```

Here is the raw version of the data above.

```
03:03,(xxx) xxx-xxxx,"VMAIL, CL",1
```

Here is data from the next row.

```
03:04,(xxx) xxx-xxxx,"LAS VEGAS, NV",1
```

Comment: Can you provide the raw source of the problem row? (and maybe the previous and next row too). I assume all the fields are comma seperated? Of course, in general it's better to not try to fix it, and let the source fix te output.

Comment: When you say raw source are you referring to the raw data or the format file? If you are referring to the raw data, then what I provided above is about as helpful as that's going to get. With it being 1.4 mil rows, I'm having to use power pivot to open the file, and what I provided is copied and pasted straight from there.

Comment: and yes all fields are comma separated.

Comment: I understand, but the pasted data only shows the parsed fields, and we're probably looking for some other bytes causing the problem. It would be best to open the raw file in a text editor and check out the data there. Hard to find a parsing problem by only looking at the already parsed data.

Comment: Understandable, let me see if I can find this one record while using a text editor.

Comment: One common issue is often system characters in the text that you cannot see in a text editor or similar (when you find the row, use a hexeditor to verify). Or maybe the field is just longer than you expect.

Comment: @Danny_ds I have found the record, and updated my question.

Comment: There seems to be an extra comma at the end of the row?

Comment: @Danny_ds sorry that was a typo, it has been corrected.

Comment: Actually, this is valid csv. That field is surrounded with quotes to escape the comma. So there is no need to rectify this. Maybe you need to set 'quoted fields' on.

Comment: In fact, adding a `"` could cause more problems if the parser treats the fields as quoted.

Comment: Set quoted fields on? What is the syntax for that?

Comment: I don't know how those format files work, but it should be a very simple (often used) setting. Usually this can be set in the same manner as setting the field seperator.

Comment: Oh, I'm not using any type of wizard. Both my bulk insert and my format file are programmed out without the aid of a wizard or program.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Thanks for you input. I did as you suggested, and this was the output  `00000000 2c 22 56 4d 41 49 4c 2c 20 43 4c 22 2c    ,"VMAIL, CL",_` I have no idea what any of that means, but I compared it to another line that was able to be imported successfully, and they looked exactly the same.